# Sails.JS image uploading not working in production? Works in development staging

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vue.js, sails.js, digital-ocean

I use Vue.JS for the frontend and Sails.JS for the backend.

Everything is working in my local machine and production, except image uploading.

I get these errors:

```
POST http://{mysailsdomain}/api/v1/upload 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Failed To Load http://{mysailsdomain}/api/v1/upload: No 'Access-Control-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://{myvuedomain}' is therfore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 413.

Uncaught (in promise) B {url: "http://{mysailsdomain}/api/v1/upload", ok: false, status: 0, statusText: "", headers: U, …}

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://{mysailsdomain}/api/v1/upload with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

My `config/security.js`

```
cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false,
  },
```

I googled the error around and someone suggested to add this code to my `config/http.js`

```
bodyParser: (function () {
      var opts = {limit:'50mb'};
      var fn;

      // Default to built-in bodyParser:
      fn = require('skipper');
      return fn(opts);

    })
```

I added the code, but the issue persists.

Here's my `production.js`:

```
onlyAllowOrigins: [
   'http://{myvuejsdashboard}',
   'http://{myvuejsapp}'
 ]
```

I even tried to comment out all the `onlyAllowOrigins` but still no luck.

I'm using Sails v1.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

What is your production environment setup ? Is it behind a proxy server ngnix, it looks like that your proxy server is rejecting the uploaded since there is limit set on proxy server.

If you are using ngnix you can set client_max_body_size to 50MB in ngnix config and restart your ngnix to reload config.

This should fix your first problem. [ 413 (Request Entity Too Large) ]